# Javascript Noob wants to ask about onclick events

Tags: javascript, django, forms, templates

I'm currently writing a template for a django project and am a complete javascript beginner. The part of my template in question looks like this:

```
<form action='/gh/' method='GET'>
    <label>Synchronisation:</label>
    <input type='image' src='/site_media/images/sync.png' height='27', width='27' onclick="return confirm('Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie Synchronisieren wollen?');" alt="Synchronisation"></input>
  </form>
```

Now if i click the image (sync.png) I get a confirm box where I can choose Ok or Cancel. Now If Ok is clicked i would like to show an image. How do I have to write this?

Comment: FYI, The question title should be a summary of your question, not that it is a question about javascript. We know that from 1. you're on StackOverflow, 2. the javascript tag. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a confirm box: so you have to do something like this:
Creat a function to call on the on click:

```
function button_on_click(){
    if(confirm('Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie Synchronisieren wollen?'))
    {
         //when ok is pushed do somehting here
         var element = document.getElementById('image_to_show'); 
         element.css.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
         //this will handle the cancel event
    }
}
```

That ought to do the trick. so just add button_on_click() on the onclick attribute of the element